# How to iterate over const object with iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

```
void foo(const std::vector<int>& value) {
    std::vector<int>::iterator it = value.begin();
    /* functions that increment it */
}
```

I need to get non-const iterator to iterate over const object, i pass on the iterator to another functions which then increment it. But i get an error about trying to convert const_iterator to iterator. How do i get non-const iterator(if it is possible).

```
void foo(std::vector<int>& value) {
    std::vector<int>::iterator it = value.begin();
    /* functions that increment it */
}
```

Of course i tried using non-const reference but then it does not allow me to call the function like this...

```
object.foo({0,1});
```

And i know that the easiest solution would be to not take it as a reference but as a copy

```
void foo(std::vector<int> value) {
    std::vector<int>::iterator it = value.begin();
    /* functions that increment it */
}
```

but i want to make it as effective as possible (both time and memory).

Comment: If you want to get a non-constant iterator from a constant container, then you're probably doing something wrong. I would recommend you go back to your design and see if you can come up with something that doesn't add that requirement.

Comment: Why do you need non-const iterator to iterate over const object? If you need to modify it, why do you have a const vector in the first place?

Comment: Change `std::vector<int>::iterator` to `std::vector<int>::const_iterator`.     In C++11 and later, use `auto` and let the compiler work it out, or use a range-based for loop.    More generally, read the documentation for the standard containers.   There is a difference between incrementing an iterator (which changes what element of the container it references) and being able to use an iterator to change elements of a container.   You're confusing the two.

Comment: If your vector is `const`, your iterator has to be `const_iterator`, i.e. `    std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = value.begin();`

Comment: I am not modifying it, i'm reading through the vector by passing iterator and end iterator. I use it to move the currently read  value.

Comment: So you *do* (indirectly) modify the contents of the vector? That's why it's so important to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. Just saying "do stuff" doesn't give us all context we need. And please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well.

Comment: No, i do not modify anything. I only read from the vector and increment the iterator.

Comment: If you are not modifying elements of the vector, `const_iterator` is enough.   If you have other functions that expect an `iterator` you need to modify them to be able to accept a `const_iterator`.   Trying to force a `const` container to give you an `iterator` (which allows treating the container as if it is not `const`) is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use std::vector<>::const_iterator.

Comment: I find it amusing that the first sentence is "I need to get non-const iterator to iterate over const object", well...